# How to get rid of the smell from the fridge?

Tags: smell, refrigerator, freezing

Storing various meals and products in fridge (or freezer) can result in mixing different flavours, which isn't that great. What are your best practises to avoid the smell?

Comment: I'm guessing but the down-vote is likely since "fridge smell" isn't exactly a culinary issue. It's a housekeeping problem.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't specific enough. I don't mean bad smell from the old fridge, I mean having various "nice" flavours that, when mixed, aren't nice any more. Putting everything in boxes is an option, of course, but I'm wondering is there anything more to do.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Baking soda seems to work well for me, but the best thing is to get rid of old food that is causing the smell, and seal strong-smelling foods in airtight containers.

Comment: +1 for "seal strong-smelling foods in airtight containers". If food is contaminated by smell, it's possible to get bacterial cross contamination between the foods too. Sealed containers!

Answer (score 3):

Or try coffee bean.  Put a small container of coffee bean in with some holes on the lid so that the coffee aroma can evaporate.  Coffee bean will absorb the odor.

Comment: Used, dried coffee grounds will do it too; the contents of the discard bin from an espresso machine etc, transferred into an open container is dry enough to put straight in the fridge.

Answer (score 2):

In order,to avoid bad smell after defrosting, I use vinegar.
Clean up fridge inside with rag wetted with vinegar.